# How get suggestion using jquery ui autocomplete from remote server

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

this is jquery code I have written for auto complete , I need some code to be written inside post method

```
$(function(){$('#sug').autocomplete({
source:function(req,response){
$.post('sugestskul.php',{"term":req.term},function(data){

//what code should be written here to get suggestions

},'json')
},
minLength:1,
delay:500,
max:10,
});
});
```

Data returned from server looks this way:

```
{"0":"Good Shepherd English Medium School","school":"Good Shepherd English Medium School"
```

Comment: Have you tried the typehead.js?
It's will free you of some pain...

Comment: No ,I don't know what typehead.js is ?

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ Try it... its more simple

Comment: Should any .css be included along with it

Comment: Thank you ,where can I find its documentation

Comment: docs here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js